# Proving an inequality involving definite integrals.

Tags: definite-integrals, integral-inequality

Consider a probability distribution $f(x)$ with the assumption $\int_0^{\infty}f(x) > 1/2$. I am trying to prove the following inequality:

\begin{align}
\left( \int_0^{\infty}\int_{-u}^{0}f(x)f(u)dxdu +\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)f(u)dxdu \right) >
& \int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-\infty}^{-u}f(x)f(u)dxdu.
\end{align}

My attempt is as follows:

\begin{align}
LHS &= 
\left( \int_0^{\infty}\int_{-u}^{0}f(x)f(u)dxdu +\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)f(u)dxdu \right) \\
&= \left( \int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-x}^{\infty}f(x)f(u)dudx +\int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_0^{\infty}f(x)f(u)dudx \right) \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(x) \left( \int_{-x}^{\infty}f(u)du +  \int_{0}^{\infty}f(u)du \right)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{0} f(u) \left( \int_{-u}^{\infty}f(x)dx +  \int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx \right)du. \\
\end{align}

I am stuck at this step. I used the following MATLAB simulation to prove the last step using a Gaussian family of distributions

$$
f(x,u) = f(x)f(u) = \frac{1}{2 \pi (2m)} e^{\frac{-(x-m)^2}{(2m)}} e^{\frac{-(u-m)^2}{(2m)}}.
$$
The constant $\frac{1}{2 \pi (2m)}$ is ignored in the simulation.

```
close all; clear all;clc;
mvals = (1e-5:.1:5);
q1 = zeros(1, length(mvals));
q2 = q1;
q3 = q1;
for i=1:length(mvals);
    mval = mvals(i);
    sigma2 = 2*abs(mval);
    % Function
    fun1 = @(x,y) exp(-(x-mval).^2./(2*sigma2)) .* exp(-(y-mval).^2./(2*sigma2));
    ymax = @(x) -x;
    % LHS Integrals
    q1(i) = integral2(fun1, -Inf, 0, ymax, Inf);
    q2(i) = integral2(fun1, -Inf, 0, 0, Inf);

    % RHS Integral
    q3(i) = integral2(fun1, -Inf, 0, -Inf, ymax);
end
figure('Color', [1 1 1]);
plot(mvals, q1, 'b'); hold on;
plot(mvals, q2, 'r'); hold on;
plot(mvals, q1+q2, 'g'); hold on;
plot(mvals, q3, 'k');
```

I would appreciate any help/hints.

Comment: i think the 2nd term on the lhs is bigger by itself, unless you are keenly interested in the strictness of the inequality.

Comment: @mike I just ran the simulation for your comment. The inequality you described fails for roughly $m<0.2$ in the case of above mentioned family of curves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another answer showed, this inequality does not hold in general. But I will show that it holds for the normal distribution. Assume that $f(x)$ is a normal $N(\mu,1)$ density, therefore , $f(x) =\phi(x-\mu) $and denote $F(x) = \Phi(x-\mu)$ the cumulative distribution function. $\phi()$ and $\Phi()$ are the standard normal density and cdf respectively. $\mu>0$ to reflect the assumption that the probability mass is greater in the positive orthant.
Then

\begin{align}
\left( \int_0^{\infty}\int_{-u}^{0}f(x)f(u)dxdu +\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{0}f(x)f(u)dxdu \right) >
& \int_{-\infty}^{0}\int_{-\infty}^{-u}f(x)f(u)dxdu
\end{align}

$$\Rightarrow  \int_0^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\left[\Phi(-\mu)-\Phi(-u-\mu)\right]du +\int_0^{\infty}\Phi(-\mu)\phi(u-\mu)du \;>\; \int_{-\infty}^{0}\Phi(-u-\mu)\phi(u-\mu)du $$

Break and rearrange to obtain
$$\Rightarrow  2\Phi(-\mu)\int_0^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)du  \;>\; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Phi(-u-\mu)du \qquad [1]$$

Now, regarding the LHS, by the properties of integration we can subtract $\mu$ from the limits of integration and add it to the argument. So we get

$$\int_0^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)du = \int_{-\mu}^{\infty}\phi(u)du = 1-\Phi(-\mu) = \Phi(\mu) \qquad [2]$$
the last equality from the symmetry properties of the normal.

For the RHS we can write 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Phi(-u-\mu)du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Phi(-(u+\mu))du$$
and using the symmetry properties of the normal we can write further
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Phi(-u-\mu)du = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Big[1-\Phi(u+\mu)\Big]du$$

$$=1\cdot\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)du-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Phi(u+\mu)du$$

$$=1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Phi(u+\mu)du $$

since the first integral equals unity. Using again integral properties, we subtract $\mu$ from the limits of integration and add it to the integrating variable to obtain

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u-\mu)\Phi(-u-\mu)du = 1 - \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u)\Phi(u+2\mu)du \qquad [3] $$

Inserting results $[2]$ and $[3]$ into $[1]$ we want to prove the following inequality:

$$...\Rightarrow 2\Phi(-\mu)\Phi(\mu)\;>\; 1- \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u)\Phi(u+2\mu)du\qquad [4]$$

Regarding the remaining integral in $[4]$ the following general result holds ([see for example here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions)):

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(z)\Phi(a+bz)dz = \Phi\left(\frac {a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)$$
In our case, $a= 2\mu$ and $b=1$ so

$$1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\phi(u)\Phi(u+2\mu)du = 1-\Phi\left(\frac {2\mu}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = 1-\Phi(\sqrt2 \mu) = \Phi(-\sqrt2 \mu) \qquad [5]$$
using again the symmetry property. Inserting $[5]$ into $[4]$ we have

$$...\Rightarrow 2\Phi(-\mu)\Phi(\mu)\;>\; \Phi(-\sqrt2 \mu)$$

$$\Rightarrow 2\Phi(\mu)\;>\; \frac {\Phi(-\sqrt2 \mu)}{\Phi(-\mu)}$$

This inequality holds $\forall \mu>0$ since $\Phi(\mu) >1/2 \Rightarrow 2\Phi(\mu)>1$ and 
$\Phi(-\sqrt2 \mu) < \Phi(-\mu)$.

It can be reasonably conjectured that the inequality will hold for any distribution with a cdf that satisfies the symmetry property $F(x) = 1-F(-x)$, but this needs a proof on its own.

Comment: Though your conclusion is right, your example is not..  $f(u)=1/(b-a)$ but not $1$ when you plug in.

Comment: @MoonKnight Thanks for spotting the mistake -the habit of working all the time with $U(0,1)$... Since your answer showed that the inequality does not hold in general, I changed mine to show that it does hold for the normal distribution.

Comment: Thanks @AlecosPapadopoulos. That really helped.

Comment: Nice to hear. One can also show that the inequality will hold if the distribution is a uniform $U(a,b)$, $a<0<b,\; b>-a$.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos Can you please explain how you came up with the second step after "break and rearrange ... " and the second last step with $\Phi(-\sqrt{2})$. Secondly, I think the same proof holds for any [symmetric distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_probability_distribution), not necessarily Gaussian. Can you comment on this as well ? It is because, if I am correct, you have used the symmetry property of Gaussian distribution about its mean in the second step ?

Comment: I have made my answer more detailed in its steps.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I think your statement is not true in general. It might be true for some specific distribution you tried. But the condition you give is not sufficient.

Here is a counter example.
$f(x)=0.55\delta(x-2)+0.05\delta(x+1)+0.4\delta(x+3)$

$$
\int_0^\infty \left[du \int_{-u}^0f(x)f(u)dx\right]=0.55*0.05=0.0275
$$

$$
\int_0^\infty \left[du \int_{-\infty}^0f(x)f(u)dx\right]=0.55*(0.05+0.4)=0.2475
$$

$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 \left[du \int_{-\infty}^{-u}f(x)f(u)dx\right]=(0.4+0.05)*(0.4+0.05)+0.4*0.55=0.4225
$$

Your inequality does not hold since $0.0275+0.2475<0.4225$.

More illustration, the first integral takes the space
[image]

The second integral takes the space
[image]

The third integral on the RHS takes the space
[image]

The red points above are the only possible points that my example can allow.

Comment: thanks for your detailed reply. You are right. I think the inequality would be true if we restrict the distributions further to only symmetric distributions, i.e., in above mentioned example, $f(x) = e^{-x} f(-x)$. Could you please comment on this or should I ask a separate question ? This symmetry condition is available in my problem, but I thought I might not need it.

Comment: @ubaabd, I prefer you start a new question. btw, your symmetry here looks weird because if $f(x)=e^{-x}f(-x)$, then $\forall x>0, f(x)<f(-x)$.

Comment: you are right its $f(x) = e^x f(-x)$. Sorry about that.

Comment: @ubaabd. I'm not sure how to construct a distribution function from this "symmetry", but if you only want to prove for the Gaussian you mentioned above. Here is the proof.

Comment: Yes. A proof for the Gaussian would work for me. There are no links under "Here is the proof". Can you please explain what do you mean by "Here is the proof" ?

Comment: sorry it takes longer than I expected. I am writing it in a new answer. Please be patient

Comment: I have to leave now, but I will come back with a proof for Gaussian tonight.

Comment: Sure ... Thanks for your help

Comment: @ubaabd, please check Alecos' answer for the proof in the case of Gaussian.